# Javascript Bootstrap table not loading data despite different call syntax attempts

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I have a problem when calling the load method from the bootstrap method. My code is on JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/VGerardsson/uxc8wLq4/23/

I am using JQuery 3.3.1 and bootstrap 4.3.1

I followed the templates and I used several different calls to fill the table. Initially I called a URL to fill the table but this caused a time-out error. My current error, however, is that I can only display an empty table at best.

Using the answers from questions that I checked here on StackOverflow, I couldn't find an answer. I used, amongst other the two methods below. Only the `load` call returns a result but it is an empty table. the parameter `data-toggle="table"` is already set.

```
  $table.bootstrapTable('load', Mydata)
  $table.bootstrapTable({data: data})
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Let me know if the JFiddle is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code had two errors.

***1st***: you did not initialize the `$table` variable.
***2nd***: you have to provide the `data-field` attribute in the `th` tags.
I have made the changes, you can have a look at it.

Make sure to correct the json data as well.

here's the updated fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/o39z2dse/3/

Make sure to use the stackoverflow snippet next time to embed code. It's easier to use.